# Passing value from activity to adapter using bundle

Tags: android

I'm trying pass some values to show in my adapter. But I don't know how can I receive values on adapter.

This is my code.

```
    confirmar_pedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Upload up = new Upload();
            Intent intent = new Intent(PedidoDetalhesActivity.this, CarrinhoItemPedidoAdapter.class);
            intent.putExtra("idProd", up.getmKey().toString().trim());
            intent.putExtra("nomeProd", value);
            intent.putExtra("preco", convertendo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How can I receive in Adapter ?

HERE I'LL RECEIVE DATA

```
public class CarrinhoItemPedidoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarrinhoItemPedidoAdapter.CarrinhoViewHolder> {

    private Context mContextCarrinho;
    private List<Pedidos> mUploadsPedidoCliente;
    String passado;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public CarrinhoItemPedidoAdapter(Context context, List<Pedidos> uploadsClientes) {
        mContextCarrinho = context;
        mUploadsPedidoCliente = uploadsClientes;
    }

    @Override
    public CarrinhoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContextCarrinho).inflate(R.layout.carrinho_item, parent, false);
        return new CarrinhoViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CarrinhoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Pedidos pedCli = mUploadsPedidoCliente.get(position);


        //  holder.text_nome_item_pedido.setText(pedCli.getpedidoNmero() + pedCli.getQuantidade() + pedCli.getDescricao() + pedCli.getValor());
        //holder.text_nome_item_pedido.setText(" " + pedCli.getQuantidade() + " " + pedCli.getDescricao() + "                                          R$: " + pedCli.getValor());
        holder.text_nome_item_pedido.setText(" " + pedCli.getQuantity() + " " + pedCli.getDescricao());
        holder.text_valor_pedido.setText("R$: " + pedCli.getPrice());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploadsPedidoCliente.size();
    }

    public class CarrinhoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView text_nome_item_pedido, text_valor_pedido, text_id_pedido;
        public Button btn_excluir_item_carrinho;

        public CarrinhoViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            text_valor_pedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_valor_pedido);
            text_nome_item_pedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_nome_item_pedido);
            text_id_pedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id_pedido);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are not using the adapter as you suppose. Also to pass data to the adapter you can use its constructor.

Comment: Agreed, you are using the adapter wrong, you should pass variables through a constructor. And your adapter should be passed to a `RecyclerView`, not with intents, that's not how they work.

Comment: use constructor or setter in your adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Retreive value from intent, simply us this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
string idprod = intent.getString("idProd");
int preco = intent.getInt("preco");
```

Depending on the value if it's a string or an int or a parcelable.

Check here for more information :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: So,i know how can i pass my values , but i don't know how MY ADAPTER can get my values passed.

So , i'm using button to pass values, and i would like know how can i receive on my AdapterClass.

When i try use "Intent intent = getIntent(); " on my AdapterClass i receive line error.

Comment: @GabrielNogueira that's because you can't start an adapter with an intent, it's not an Activity, look into tutorials for RecyclerView